# CryptoJS HmacSHA256 Encryption results differ from Python

Tags: python, hmac, cryptojs

CryptoJS encrypted string can pass different parameters in python can only pass a string? How to implement the second CryptoJS implementation in python
 ,how to get clientKey2,This will only give the first result.Thanks!

```
> saltedPassword=CryptoJS.PBKDF2("key", "salt", {keySize: 8,iterations:500,hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256});    
> clientKey1=CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(saltedPassword.toString(), "Client Key")
> clientKey2=CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(saltedPassword, "Client Key")
> clientKey1.toString()
> "857ef8988876a3bb6bcadb85ca257787074e73e830d7dc14c1f838ba46aef1f5"
> clientKey2.toString()
> "9a8574da9b276ee1162dcb92071df587f4513bc03060bda1e9b3897d46233416"
> saltedPassword.toString()
> "6e441ccd26e6b35198b4b17457dc0266d36b751d0062b5850b0e302ceb1d6dcc"
```

i use this way can get clientKey1,

```
import hashlib
import hmac

def HmacSHA256(k,v):
    message = bytes(k).encode('utf-8')
    secret = bytes(v).encode('utf-8')
    signature = hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return signature

signature = HmacSHA256("6e441ccd26e6b35198b4b17457dc0266d36b751d0062b5850b0e302ceb1d6dcc","Client Key")

print signature
```

How to get the second result in Python,Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You question is heavily based on code. Please make sure to explain your problem **before** posting any code. Introduce the code itself and explain what it does. You could then finalise your question by adding a specific question at the end. In any case, make sure to read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired `clientKey2` you need to encode the hex digits of your `saltedPassword` string to bytes. One way to do that which works on both Python 2 & Python 3 is to use [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

Your `HmacSHA256` function is a bit odd. It won't work on Python 3, since `bytes` objects don't have an `.encode` method. In Python 2, `bytes` is just a synonym for `str`.

Anyway, here's some code that works on both Python 2 & Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import hashlib
import hmac
import binascii

key = "Client Key".encode()
salted = "6e441ccd26e6b35198b4b17457dc0266d36b751d0062b5850b0e302ceb1d6dcc"
raw = binascii.unhexlify(salted)

signature = hmac.new(key, salted.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(signature)

signature = hmac.new(key, raw, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

**output**

```
857ef8988876a3bb6bcadb85ca257787074e73e830d7dc14c1f838ba46aef1f5
9a8574da9b276ee1162dcb92071df587f4513bc03060bda1e9b3897d46233416
```

The output is identical on Python 2 & Python 3.

BTW, it would be simpler to do this task in Python 3, which makes a clean distinction between text and byte strings. Also, the Python 3 `hashlib` module has a [`pbkdf2` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac).